# 'Degenerate' tangent point of a minimal graph

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, minimal-surfaces

Let $u: D_1 \to \mathbf{R}$ be a smooth function defined on the unit disk $D_1 \subset \mathbf{R}^2$ which describes the minimal graph $G$. Suppose that at the origin $G$ is tangent to the horizontal plane $\{ x^{3} = 0 \}$, that is:  $u(0) = 0$ and $Du(0) = 0$. Suppose that in a small disk $D_r$ around the origin, the intersection of $G$ and the plane decomposes like
\begin{equation}
\{ u = 0 \} \cap D_r \setminus \{ 0 \} = \gamma_1 \cup \cdots \cup \gamma_4.
\end{equation}
The $\gamma_i$ are smooth curves meeting at right angles at the origin, their common endpoint. After rotation, we may assume that $\gamma_1'(0) = e_1$, $\gamma_2'(0) = e_2$, $\gamma_3'(0) = -e_1$ and $\gamma_4'(0) = -e_2$.

> Is it possible for $\gamma_1 \cup \gamma_2$ to form a graph over the $x^1$-axis, that is can there be $\varphi \in C^0(-r,r)$ so that $\gamma_1 \cup \gamma_2 = \{ (t,\varphi(t),0) \mid t \in (-r,r) \}$?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the setup since how can the union of two curves be a single graph. But have you considered ennepers surface? If you intersect with the right tangent plane you'll get two straight lines (usually this is the xy plane through the origin)

Comment: @OtisChodosh Ultimately I was hoping one could say that $\gamma_1$ intersects the first coordinate axis (to which it is tangent at the origin). For the Enneper surface, I think $\gamma_1$ would coincide with it. I phrased the question like this because I thought it might be easier to exclude this extreme case. So for example, to say that $\gamma_2$ cannot be the graph of $x_1 \mapsto \sqrt{-x_1}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Consider the intersection of the helicoid $z = \tan^{-1}(y/x)$ with its tangent plane $z = y$ at $(1,0,0)$. The projection of the intersection curves to $\{z = 0\}$ consists of the line $y = 0$ and the curve $x = y/\tan(y) \sim 1 - y^2/3$. After a rigid motion so that the tangent plane is horizontal and the tangent point is the origin, the union of $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ will be a $C^{1/2}$ graph $\{(t,\,\varphi(t),\,0)\}$ where $\varphi(t) = 0$ for $t \geq 0$ and $\varphi(t) \sim (-6t)^{1/2}$ for $t < 0$.

One can generate many more examples using Cauchy-Kovalevskaya, by choosing appropriate Cauchy data on a line segment through 0 and solving the minimal surface equation in a neighborhood of the origin. For example, taking $u = 0$ and $u_y = x + x^2/2$ on $\{y = 0\}$ gives
$$u = xy + \frac{1}{2}x^2y - \frac{1}{6}y^3 + O((x^2+y^2)^2),$$
hence $\{u = 0\}$ locally resembles the line $y = 0$ and the curve $y^2 = 6x$.

Comment: This is so cool, thanks! Did your reasoning go something as follows? You saw that there examples that are harmonic functions, and then the helicoid was a natural guess, and the calculations worked out at the point? And as for 'why' there 'should' be harmonic examples, it seems like it's got something to do with $u$ being decomposed into different frequencies, with them interacting at intermediate scales - is there an explanation along these lines?

Comment: Sure! Yes, playing with harmonic functions (expansions of minimal surfaces over their tangent planes) was the key. The helicoid is one of my favorite examples because it's harmonic and infinity-harmonic, thus minimal (since the MSE is Laplace - (Infinity Laplace)/(1+grad^2) = 0).